# Regex improvement

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

`/%%[\s\S]*?%%/i`

It's meant to catch these types of strings:

`%%test%%`

`%%test2%%`

However, because this regex runs on big strings, sometimes there are mistakes, for example if i have this:

`%test%% adhja kshdjah skdja %%test1%%` it will return `%% adhja kshdjah skdja %%`

The strings that it is supposed to catch never have any spaces in them, how can I alter my regex to take only the ones with no spaces?

Comment: `[\s\S]` matching whitespace and non-whitespace? equal to `.`?

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your "wrong" example. You only have one `%` at the beginning so the fraction is matched as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[^%\s]` for non `space` and non `%`.

```
/%%[^%\s]*?%%/
```

Comment: If single percent signs are to be allowed inside the `%%` delimiters you can basically just take out the percent sign after `^`.